# How to see code errors when executing from hardware device

Tags: android, logcat

I'd like to know how could I see the piece of code that is failing when my app is stopping in Android Studio.

When I use the AVD emulator I am indeed able to see from where the error comes, but when I'm using a real hardware device it just does not appear on the android logcat.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your application in android phone then logcat saves the error in the stack and as soon as the application is crashed it shows you it in red color.

Read the error carefully in bottom to top fashion.

Comment: That's my problem, there is no error shown. On my phone the app is crashing but on the logcat in the computer there is no error.

With the emulator I can easily click the error and he transports me to the piece of code that is failing.

Comment: My problem is not about me being unable to solve the problem, I just want to se if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run logcat in a shell:

```
adb logcat
```

Comment: The thing is that ATM i'm programming on Win7

Comment: Then open a shell, (Win+R) then type cmd.exe. Go to you Android SDK folder and then in "platform-tools" folder to find adb.